# hiveServer2 argument has not been provided correctly

Tags: java, r, hadoop, hive

I am connecting `R` with `Hive 0.13.1` using the package `RHive_2.0-0.2`.

But when `rhive.connect( )` is used, I get the following message:

```
Warning: 
    +----------------------------------------------------------+
    + / hiveServer2 argument has not been provided correctly.  +
    + / RHive will use a default value: hiveServer2=TRUE.      +
    +----------------------------------------------------------+

Error: java.sql.SQLException: Connection to hiveserver has timed out.
    --connection-parameters(version: hiveserver2, host:127.0.0.1, port:10000, db:default, user:null, password:null)
```

Restart `R` session and retry with correct arguments.

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Can you login to hive via beeline?

Comment: I used beeline to login successfully using the following command:

hive --service beeline

But RHive is not connecting. Any suggestions ?